# Pycaret time series cv and binary classification

Tags: pycaret

is it possible to first use cross validation with ExpandingWindowSplitter on a time series dataset and then fit the folds on classification binary models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyCaret support custom CV generator object compatible with `scikit-learn` so you can try sktime's ExpandingWindowSplitter and pass it to the `setup` step. You can find documentation about PyCaret's classification parameter from [here](https://pycaret.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/classification.html#pycaret.classification.setup)

```
from sktime.forecasting.model_selection import ExpandingWindowSplitter
from pycaret.classification import *

splitter = ExpandingWindowSplitter(fh=[2, 4], initial_window=5, step_length=2)
exp_name = setup(data = data,  target = 'target', fold_strategy=splitter)
```